# Matplotlib doesn't plot several lines at the same scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Hi I'm trying to plot several lines in the same plot in the same scale.
Unfortunately  get very weird results.
Here is my code that import data from csv file:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('SKY_298Output_power.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')


    count = 0;
    freqcount = 1;

    for row in plots:
        if count < 2:
            prevFreq = row[0]
        curFreq = row[0]

        if curFreq != prevFreq:

            plt.plot(x, y, label=f"{prevFreq}MHz")
            x = []
            y = []
            freqcount += 1
            prevFreq = curFreq

        x.append(row[1])
        y.append(row[2])
        count += 1
    plt.plot(x, y, label=f"{prevFreq}MHz")
    plt.xticks(rotation=25)
    plt.xlabel('Pin [dBm]')
    plt.ylabel('Pout [dBm]')
    plt.title('Pout[dBm] vs Pin [dBm] ', fontsize=20)
    plt.grid()
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

[image: The plot I get]

thank you!!

Comment: I guess your y-data are strings. Convert them into floats.

Comment: Yes you are right!!! Thank you a lot!!!